# Preview Scale to Fit should be 100%, yet it's saying a different scale

Tags: preview, printing

I've been printing on a plotter at 36x24. When scaling, despite the image being 36x24, it says "scale to fit" is at 95%. Since I'm printing for construction, the scale has to be exact. Why is it not matching up? This is only a problem on my computer, my coworker isn't having the same issue.

Comment: Print margins? tbh we have nothing to work from. We need detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is that inches or centimetres?

Answer (score 1):

In Preview's print menu, select "Scale" and set to 100%.

"Scale to Fit", unsurprisingly, scales the image to fit the page. This includes any print area margins that your device might operate to.

The Printer driver will contain information about the print margins. If someone else is getting different results with the same settings, then their print driver may be different.

[image]